# How to identify live objects while traversing the heap?

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers

(Context: The system I am working on already maintains a form of garbage collection. I'm working on compaction.)

Most compaction algorithms follow a basic structure:

1. Find first object
2. Move object to beginning of heap
3. Find second object
4. Move second object to address right after first object
5. Rinse and repeat

This algorithm is followed in section 2.2 of [this paper](https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/systems/rs/papers/ParCompac_OOPSLA04.pdf) except using two pointers, denoted "from" and "to". Essentially the FROM pointer traverses the heap until it finds live objects. Then it moves said object to the TO pointer. Then TO is incremented accordingly.

The algorithm is simple, but I have yet to find much information on how these pointers determine what is a "live object". [This article](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2013/12/08/babys-first-garbage-collector/) discusses the creation of a basic mark-and-sweep garbage collector that runs through the stack, recursively going to each reference and marking them as live. The article however requires a linked list of ALL objects ever allocated. However, this is because the author is more or less creating their own VM.

My question is, is there a way of traversing a heap in C and identifying whether the current object is a live object? Is there a similar linked list of all allocated objects already in C that I could use? Or will I require more overhead?

Comment: There is no such thing in C. However you can implement a ref counter for each object. When the counter reach 0, it means it went out of the scope and can be recycled.

Comment: @FrancescoLaurita You mean reference counting for garbage collection? Garbage collection isn't an issue, it's compaction I am contending with. Seems like my hopes and wishes for C are non-existent though :(

Comment: I was referring to your question on how to identify whether a current object is in use or not. Counting the references for each object would be a strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: It's impossible.

To make that work, you need to solve some non-trivial problems:

1. Be able to name the live objects of the heap. That means to find and follow recursively all pointers in global variables and on the stack.
2. Move the live objects downwards to create a compact heap
3. Adjust pointers in your program to reflect the new locations of the moved objects.

Regarding 1.: At runtime, the C language doesn't help you to identify where you have pointer-type global variables. And on the stack, you find a mixture of e.g. integers, function-call return addresses or data pointers. For both memory areas, you have to find a way to enumerate all potential pointer values.

To make things worse, a pointer can not only point to the beginning of your data structure, but also to some inside element. And this pointer also makes the whole object "live".

Regarding 2.: That's the easy part, using the algorithm you mentioned.

Regarding 3.: Now your objects live at new addresses, so your old pointer values are no longer correct (pointing to the old locations), and you have to adjust them. So once again, you have to follow all root references (like in 1.) and adjust all pointers that are affected by your moves. But as you can't tell for sure if e.g. 0x12345678 was meant as an numeric integer or as an (old-location) address, changing that to the new-location address might break some computation.

Comment: Yes I was worried even the `type` was going to be a problem. I was hoping it was just my lacking knowledge of C. This really outlines the issue, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, is there a way of traversing a heap in C and identifying whether the current object is a live object?

At a high level, the process is looking at all active pointers and determining whether or not each piece of allocated memory is accessible. (Please note that this is very complicated is C, including because a pointer could be stored in an int or other data types.) If the memory is accessible via a pointer, then it is "live" in your terms. If not, then garbage collectors would consider it safe to free that memory.

If you're asking whether or not C has a native function for determining whether or not some allocated memory can be reached, then the answer is no.

> Is there a similar linked list of all allocated objects already in C that I could use? Or will I require more overhead?

Again, if you're looking for a linked list that C natively provides and you can access, then the answer is no. You'd need to implement these things.

Forgive me if you've already seen this, but there are [garbage collectors](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) that you can download if you want to see how others have done it.

Comment: Hmm, that is unfortunate. Thanks for the comprehensive answer though. As for Boehm-Demers-Weiser, it's a bit difficult because I don't need garbage collection, only compaction. Most compactions seem to work off of the results of garbage collection but unfortunately I have very little accommodation for more overhead in my project.